# Find the total number of solutions to $3^{\cos x}=\left|\sin x\right|$ in the interval $\left[-2\pi,2\pi\right]$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the total number of solutions to $3^{\cos x}=\left|\sin x\right|$ in the interval $\left[-2\pi,2\pi\right]$.

My attempt (without using calculus): I attempted to draw a rough sketch of the two equations over a period of $2\pi$ on either side of the equality operator and tried to pull out some conclusions. This might seem extremely stupid, I apologize in advance. But could someone help by solving this problem without using calculus? It hasn't been done for us yet, I'm looking for a high school-level solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you can define $\cos$ and $\sin$ using geometry. Not easy task. But... $3^{\cos x}$ without calculus is impossible.

Comment: I doubt that you can do that at high school-level. You cannot even explain what $3^{\cos x}$ is.

Comment: Substitute $ \sin x = t$, then we want to solve $ 3^{2 \cos x } = |\sin x | ^2 \Rightarrow 3^{2t} = 1 - t^2 $ subject to $ -1 \leq t \leq 1$. However, arguing about the exact number of solutions on $[-1, 0]$ where both functions are increasing, is quite tricky and almost certainly requires some calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best what is possible without calculus.

Let us first observe

1. No multiple $k\pi$ of $\pi$ with $k \in \mathbb Z$ is a solution because $e^y$ does no zeros, but $\sin (k\pi) = 0$.
2. Both $3^{\cos x}$ and $\lvert \sin x \rvert$ have period $2\pi$.

By periodicity the number of solutions on $(\pi,2\pi)$ and $(-2\pi,-\pi)$ agrees with the number of solutions on $(-\pi,0)$ and  $(0,\pi)$, respectively.

Moreover the number of solutions on $(-\pi,0)$ agrees with the number of solutions on $(0,\pi)$ because $\cos(-x) = \cos x$ and $\lvert \sin(-x) \rvert = \lvert -\sin x \rvert = \lvert \sin x \rvert$. This means that $x \in (0,\pi)$ is a solution if and only $-x \in (-\pi,0)$ is a solution.

Therefore the number of solutions  on $[-2\pi,2\pi]$ is four times the number of solutions  on $(0,\pi)$.

$3^{\cos x}$ is strictly decreasing on $(0,\pi/2]$ and $\lvert \sin x \rvert$ strictly decreasing on $(0,\pi/2]$. For $\xi = \pi/2$ we get $3^{\cos \xi} = 3^0 = 1$ and $\lvert \sin\xi \rvert = 1$, thus $\xi =\pi/2$ is a solution, and it is the only solution on $(0,\pi/2]$ because for $0 < x < \pi/2$ we have $3^{\cos x} - \lvert \sin x \rvert > 3^{\cos \xi} - \lvert \sin \xi \rvert  = 0$.

On the interval $(\pi/2,\pi)$ I do not see what we can do without calculus. Actually there is one more solution.

[image]